# Unity 2D create circle and split into segments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a circle that is divided into a certain number of segments in Unity 2D. The segments should have their own colors and matching colliders. With the following code I managed to get an adjustable number of segments that form a kind of circle. However, I can't get this to be displayed in the simulator, i only see it in the scene.

```cs
public int segments = 8;
public Material segmentMaterial;

void Start()
{
    float angle = 0f;
    float angleStep = 360f / segments;
    Vector2 center = transform.position;

    for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
    {
        GameObject segment = new GameObject("Segment" + i);
        segment.transform.parent = transform;

        var segmentCollider = segment.AddComponent<PolygonCollider2D>();
        var segmentRenderer = segment.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        Vector2[] segmentVertices = new Vector2[3];
        segmentVertices[0] = center;
        segmentVertices[1] = center + new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle), Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle));
        angle += angleStep;
        segmentVertices[2] = center + new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle), Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle));

        segmentCollider.points = segmentVertices;

        segmentRenderer.material = segmentMaterial;

        segment.transform.position = transform.position;
        segment.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
    }
}
```

Is it because the sprite renderer needs a sprite? But this would be different forms depending on the number of segments. Is there a solution for this, how I can do this on the code side?

By the way, I need this to be a GameObject, not a canvas, since it will be my "player".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a sprite for this to work. Try to attach all those properties to an object you already have created rather than creating one in the script.

Also have a look at your camera settings, it is possible that you have set the clipping plane in such a manner that you can't see the circle.

Comment: It is better to show the answer with example, image and code.  Thank you.